# How do I bind and ejb in Tomcat 9?

Tags: jsp, ejb

I have a fairly old WAR/EAR file that I have been told to migrate from a legacy server onto a new Solaris-based Tomcat 9 install.

I am getting an error in catalina.out :

```
Exception:An exception has been raised in UserManagerBD constructor:Name [ejb/UserManagerEJB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ejb].
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I don't have all of the source code available, so re-compiling isn't an option.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't fix it if you're using any version of Tomcat. Migrating it to a full Java EE server as suggested in the answer below without source code will still be challenging for someone that knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tomcat](https://learn.redhat.com/t5/General/Can-I-use-for-EJB-applications-on-Tomcat-9/td-p/6652) doesn't provide EJB support:

> Tomcat only provides the Servlet container and a few other APIs, such as JDBC Connection pools (Datasources). **It does not provide** a transaction manager, **EJB container**, and other APIS and components from a complete, certified Java EE or Jakarta EE application server.

Use instead [WildFly](https://wildfly.org) or [TomEE](https://tomee.apache.org)

> The OpenSource project for JBoss EAP is WildFly
>
> The Apache Foundation also provides **TomEE, which is Tomcat + the remaining Java EE APIs and services**

Another option is [Installing TomEE using war](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/staging/openejb/trunk/content/installation-drop-in-war.html)

> TomEE can be setup by deploying a .war file into an existing Tomcat installation, as opposed to using the all-in-one bundle